# About models of ZFC and models in general.

Tags: set-theory

So I've been attending lectures in Set Theory lately and been struggling with the following.

When studying the universe of sets V our approach is: let ZFC be consistent, then a model V of the theory must look like this. Moreover we work with structures M in the language of set theory, which are defined as subclasses of V with a relation. If said relation is the relation in V restricted to M, then the structure is said to be standard. Now, at some point or another we prove that a certain structure satisfies the ZFC axioms (e.g. $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal) and hence that it is a model of ZFC. I fail to see how we can be so sure of this. Basically, how do we know that the structure is in fact a model and does not fall sooner or later into some contradiction?

For example, when working in propositional logic we might treat at some point what we think is a valuation that semantically entails a theory, but that turns out to be inconsistent when looked at in its whole, can't this be the case too when we work with what appears to be a structure that satisfies some theory in predicate logic?

When I asked my lecturer I received an answer of the form: we assume consistency of the meta-language, but I think I need some further insight into what this might mean.

Thank you.

EDIT: By "falling into some contradiction/inconsintency" I mean existing a sentence $\phi$ such that both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ are true. This should never happen in a model, and I fail to see why we are not proving it when working with what we aspire to consider a model (e.g. some subclass of V the universe of sets with a binary relation).

Comment: A collection of sentences has a model iff it is consistent. That is the completeness theorem.

You have some confused use of terminology that is obscuring what you mean. What does it mean for a model to "fall ... into some contradiction"? Models, by definition, satisfy precisely one of $\phi$ and $\neg \phi$ for every sentence $\phi$ in the language at hand. A collection of sentences can imply a contradiction, however, a model can't (partly because it doesn't type check, however, it is also true that the theory of a model can't imply a contradiction).

Comment: Well the thing is, we work with an abstract object M, which we say is a model, but by saying so we imply that there is no sentence in the language such that itself and its negation are both true in M (that's what I meant when saying "fall into some contradiction"). We however, at least when working with a subclass of V with a binary relation, never prove this. I do not understand why this is the case.

Comment: Wait, wait --- you don't have to know that $M$ is a model to know that a sentence and its negation can't both be true in $M$.

Comment: @Anguepa Yes you do, by fiat. A sub-class $M$ of $V$ with the relation $\in$ is a model (of something), because, a model is just a set (class) with some functions, relations, and constants tacked along. So, there are various sentences in the language with $\in$, for each such sentence, precisely one of $M\models \phi$ and $M\models \neg \phi$ is going to be true, by the definition if $\models$. So, you show that, in particular, $M$ models all the axioms of ZFC, and hence, is a model of ZFC. Now, it might have a different theory than the big model $V$, but that is ok.

Comment: @James:  I think, but am not certain, that your last comment was intended for me, not for Anguepa.  If so, I utterly fail to follow you.  You don't have to know anything about model theory to know 17 is not simultaneously prime and not-prime.

Comment: @WillO perhaps you should have listened to your intuition. It was not directed at you, indeed, there is even a tag to the OP at the very beginning of my comment. Finally, although your meta-theory may contain no contradictions, it is a matter of definition whether a model can satisfy a sentence and its negation.

Comment: @James Ok I think I follow you, it is sort of the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I hope you don't mind if I ask you a last question that your answer has made me wonder. Given a model in a language, for a sentence $\phi$ in the language either $\phi$ or $\neg\phi$ has to be true in the model. Now, if a consistent theory $T$ in the language is such that $T\nvdash \phi$ and $T\nvdash\neg\phi$ then by the completeness theorem there must exists models of both $T\cup \{\phi\}$ and $T\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ and so $\phi$ is independent of $T$.

Comment: @James does that make sense?

Comment: @Anguepa That is correct, if $T \cup \{\phi\}$ and $T\cup \{\neg \phi\}$ are both consistent, then they both have models, and $\phi$ is independent of $T$. Because of the completeness theorem, it doesn't matter whether you talk about a statement following via proof, or via truth, they are both the same.